# Decoding qr code using zxing

Tags: c++, zxing

Hello i read this topic [How to decode data using Zxing C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973641/how-to-decode-data-using-zxing-c/17991002#17991002) but this didn't resolve my issue. I tries to follow this http://wiki.ssrrsummerschool.org/doku.php?id=robocup2012:qrcode-cppexample but when I #include this class error occures:

```
IntelliSense: no default constructor exists for class "zxing::LuminanceSource".
```

So I added: `LuminasceSource(inWidth, inHeight)` to constructor

```
BufferBitmapSource::BufferBitmapSource
    (int inWidth, int inHeight, unsigned char * inBuffer) 
: LuminasceSource(inWidth, inHeight) {
    width = inWidth; 
    height = inHeight; 
    buffer = inBuffer; 
}
```

But now when I try to use this:

Ref source (new BufferBitmapSource(width, height, buffer));

I get: error C2259:

```
'qrviddec::BufferBitmapSource' : cannot instantiate abstract class.
```

How? BufferBitmapSource isn't abstract class, it has constructor and this should work. The rest source code is under second link.

Comment: If `zxing::LuminanceSource` is abstract and you haven't provided implementations for all of the pure virtual functions in `qrviddec::BufferBitmapSource` then it is abstract too.  Adding the definitions of each class will help you get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

> *"How? BufferBitmapSource isn't abstract class, it has constructor and this should work."*

That the class provides a constructor, doesn't prove it's not an *abstract* class.

Very probably `LuminasceSource` declares some pure virtual functions, and `BufferBitmapSource` doesn't implement these.

---

<sub>Also you should post a [minimal compilable and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the source code in question, instead of linking to off-site resources.</sub>